# Display (4.0) Django models.JSONFields as form in webpage

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-jsonfield

I am working on a Django based website.
I have defined a JSONFields in my backend DB table , let's called it "CampaignTable"
The JSONFields is used to store Campaign parameters which might differ from campaign to campaign.
I want to collect campaign configuration from web user in a form , this form is actually transfer from JSONFields (key:value) to Form (fields:value)
Is there a way to do it in Django or any plugins I can use ?

Comment: I've created an app called [django-jsonform](https://github.com/bhch/django-jsonform) for the admin ui to create dynamic forms from JSON schema. But it's only for the admin site.

Comment: @xyres any suggestions on how can I do it on any JSONFields ?  Is there any key part in your projects I can refer to ;)

Comment: There are other projects. Lookup "JSON schema form" on github. You'll find some good projects for your purposes.

Comment: I found something I want : https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ . I guess I need to use React as my frontend framework . Thank you for your suggestion @xyres